# Facebook comment formatting

Tags: php, css, facebook

I added the Facebook comment code in to a Wordpress comment

```
<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
<li class="reviews_tab"><a href="#tab-reviews"><div id="fb-root">
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<?php echo '<fb:comments-count href=http://bikeroger.com';
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
echo '></fb:comments-count> Awesome Love'; ?>
</a></li>
<br>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The result is what I wanted, but the styling is not.

Here's [site](http://bikeroger.com/shop/bike-roger-bike-box-rental-service/) and a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see from the image.
the text for "1656 Awesome Words" is smaller than "Description" & "Additional Information"

How can I make the font sizes the same?

Comment: Unfortunately far as I know about the FB connect (I tend to use graph) But generally either way, anything in the `<fb:...>` tags (which is FBML (facebooks rendition of HTML)) is provided as is, and you really can't do a lot about it, its one of those it is what it is things, you may but I don't know for sure be able to change it up some with javascript/jquery after it loads on the page but only after its loaded, which may or may not be a violation of there terms of use.

Comment: Ahh, I revoke my previous comment now. As I see whats meant.

Comment: snarky comment: I fail to see how anything on facebook could be considered "awesome".

Comment: Try adding `fb_comments_count` class to css and apply required formatting in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
<li class="reviews_tab"><a href="#tab-reviews"><div id="fb-root">
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<?php echo '<fb:comments-count href=http://bikeroger.com';
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
echo '></fb:comments-count> Awesome Love'; ?>
</a></li>
<br>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Above your original code...

Below a minor alteration

```
<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
<li class="reviews_tab"><a href="#tab-reviews"><div id="fb-root">
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<?php echo '<fb:comments-count href=http://bikeroger.com';
echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
echo '></fb:comments-count> Awesome Love'; ?>
</div></a></li>
<br>
<?php endif; ?>
```

inside your `li` and `a` tags you open a div tag "fb-root" but you are not closing it before closing the `a` and `li` tags. Thus having a broken tag, this may or may not be part of the issue directly but having broken unclosed tags can sometimes result in adverse undesired effects.

Also Im gonna take a wild guess and assume you have multiple div's with the ID fb-root on your page, which may also be causing conflict. However all in all. It being in the fb-root div, the facebook styling is overriding your styling as FB loads its styling after page load. So your comment tag is inheriting its styling rather than your initial styling. Facebook through that javascript you include for it, is basically rewriting the css/style properties of all elements within the fb-root div after its loaded into the DOM.